# SAS import xls only when columns have a name

Tags: sas

I have an excel file that needs to be imported periodically to sas. The names of the columns are in row 2 and the number of columns can change. I'm using the following query:

```
proc import file = "file.xlsx"
out = sasfile
dbms= excel replace;
sheet = "sheet1";
range = "sheet1$A2:BE2000";
getnames = yes;
run;
```

However, I keep getting F variables in the sas output. How can I dynamically input only the columns that have names?

Comment: What you mean by F variables?

Comment: sas names empty columns imported as F and the column number, for ex F32

Comment: Is there anyway to set a named range in Excel? Its easier to reference that, or alternatively add some logic to drop all F## columns automatically after the import. The second option is relatively easy to implement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you saying that if the column doesn't have a name in the second row then you want to remove that column from the resulting table?

It is a bit of a pain to get PROC IMPORT to read an XLSX file that is not formatted as a table since it does not support NAMEROW, STARTROW, DATAROW, etc.  But you might be able to do it by just reading the names and the data separately.

First let's create some macro variables to make the solution easy to modify.

```
%let sheetname=SHEET1;
%let startrow=2;
%let lastrow=2000;
%let startcol=A;
%let lastcol=BE;
```

Now let's read in the variable names from `&STARTROW`.

```
proc import datafile='c:\users\abernathyt\downloads\book1.xlsx' replace
  dbms=xlsx out=names1;
  range="&sheetname.$&startcol.&startrow:&lastcol.&startrow";
  getnames=no;
run;
```

And then transpose it.

```
proc transpose data=names1 out=names2;
  var _all_;
run;
```

Now let's generate `old=new` pairs for the columns we want to rename and also the list of columns that we want to drop.

```
proc sql noprint ;
  select case when col1 ne ' ' then catx('=',_name_,nliteral(trim(col1))) else ' ' end
       , case when col1 ne ' ' then ' ' else _name_ end
  into :rename separated by ' '
     , :drop separated by ' '
  from names2
  ;
quit;
```

Now let's read in the data and add dataset options to rename and/or drop columns on the way out.

```
proc import datafile='c:\users\abernathyt\downloads\book1.xlsx' replace
  dbms=xlsx out=want(rename=(&rename) drop=&drop)
;
  range="&sheetname.$&startcol.%eval(&startrow+1):&lastcol.&lastrow";
  getnames=no;
run;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are getting those because you are explicitly giving `sheet` and `range` just made a simple file and did import as expected with sas code given below

```
PROC IMPORT OUT= WORK.imported_file DATAFILE= "file.xlsx"
   DBMS=EXCEL REPLACE;
   GETNAMES=YES;
RUN;
```

If you are trying to start from a certain row you can achieve that using

```
namerow=2;
startrow=3;
```

Comment: The excel file is a template and the column names are in row 2. How can I add that without using the range option? for some reason datarow=2 or namerow=2 don't work

Comment: use `namerow=2;` and `startrow=3;`

Comment: I tried: proc import file = "file.xlsx"
out = sasfile
dbms= excel replace;
sheet = "sheet1";
namerow=2; startrow=3;
getnames = yes;
run; but i get the ERROR 180-322: Statement is not valid or it is used out of proper order

Comment: if you are giving `namerow` you should set `getnames=no`

Comment: I don't think namerow is a valid option with DBMS=Excel.

Comment: I keep getting the same error, are there any restrictions to use these options? I'm using sas 9.4

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's an easy way to prevent `proc import` from creating the named F variables. But it's not hard to remove them after the import.

First, create a macro variable containing the F vars. I've chosen to use the dictionary.columns table to find variables that begin with "F" and only contain digits from the 2nd position to the end of name. You don't want to drop variables with names such as "flag", "F12_23" or "f2var".

```
* imported table in work.xl;
proc sql noprint;
select name into :fvars separated by ', '
from dictionary.columns
where
    libname = 'WORK' and
    memname = 'XL' and
    name like 'F%' and
    notdigit(strip(name), 2) = 0
;
quit;
```

Then use `alter table` to drop the variables.

```
proc sql;
alter table xl
drop &fvars;
quit;
```

It's pretty straight-forward.